# Find all possible 3 fold cover of torus minus an open disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm studying for my upcoming geometry qualifying exam and got stuck with this problem:

Find all topological spaces that are 3 fold coverings of $S^1\times S^1$ minus an open disk.

Here is my attempt: if $X$ is a cover of the torus minus a disk, then $X$ is an orientable smooth manifold with boundary, so it is a genus $g$ surface minus $k$ disks; here $k$ is a positive integer. Since torus minus disk is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of 2 circles, it has Euler characteristic $-1$. A genus $g$ surface minus $k$ disks is homotopy equivalent to $2g+k-1$ circles, so we need $2-2g-k=-3$ by considering Euler characteristics, which implies that we have $(g,k)=(0,5),(1,3),(2,1)$. The first pair is impossible since this implies disjoint union of $5$ circles is a 3 fold cover of one circle. The second one is clearly possible. However, I'm unsure about the last one, so my question is:

Does an oriented genus 2 surface minus 2 disjoint open disks cover the torus minus one open disk?

I've tried to look at fundamental groups, but I'm not sure how that would help trying to find an explicit mapping.

Thank you in advance!